# Joining to return all rows even when there are no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a list how many products we've sold, per company, by all categories.

I'd like the results to look like:

```
Category A  Company 1    0
Category A  Company 2    0 
Category A  Company 3    5
Category B  Company 1    1 
Category B  Company 2    4
Category B  Company 3    0
```

So every category is returned, every company is returned, even if there are no sales.

This is the query I'm trying and it should make the structure of the database clear.  I've attacked this from a bunch of direction, but can't seem to wrap my head around how to get at what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT com.Company_Name, c.Category_Name,  sum(p.Quantity) 
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Item i on c.Category_ID = i.Category_ID
LEFT JOIN Products p on p.Item_ID = i.Item_ID
LEFT JOIN Invoice iv on iv.Invoice_ID = p.Invoice_ID
LEFT JOIN Company com on com.Company_Id = iv.Company_ID
group by c.Category_Name, com.Company_Name
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I think that you are right, just use an isnull(sum(p.Quantity),0)as sum_qty and you 'll get the zeros that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the rows with a cross join, then `left join` in the rest of the information:

```
SELECT co.Company_Name, ca.Category_Name, 
       COALESCE(SUM(p.Quantity), 0) as quantity 
FROM Category c CROSS JOIN
     Company co LEFT JOIN
     (Invoice iv JOIN
      Products p
      ON iv.Invoice_ID = p.Invoice_ID JOIN
      Item i
      ON p.Item_ID = i.Item_ID
     ) 
     ON co.Company_Id = iv.Company_ID AND
        c.Category_ID = i.Category_ID
GROUP BY ca.Category_Name, co.Company_Name
```

Comment: This was really helpful, but isn't quite working.  I'm getting a non-zero quantity in every combination for category/company, which just isn't the case.

Comment: It's returning the 'total quantity of all products' for that company on every line rather than the quantity of products for each category.

Comment: Are you sure the `join` conditions are correct, particularly the last one that has two conditions?

Comment: Yes.  This is the actual query:

`SELECT co.Company_Name, ca.Description, ca.IV_SubCat_RecID   
      , COALESCE(SUM(p.Quantity), 0) as quantity    
FROM IV_SubCategory ca CROSS JOIN   
     Company co LEFT JOIN  
     Billing_Log iv   
     ON co.Company_RecID = iv.Company_RecID LEFT JOIN   
     IV_Product p   
     ON iv.Billing_Log_RecID = p.Billing_Log_RecID left JOIN   
     IV_Item i   
     ON ca.IV_SubCat_RecID = i.IV_SubCat_RecID AND    
        i.IV_Item_RecID = p.IV_Item_RecID   
GROUP BY ca.Description, ca.IV_SubCat_RecID, co.Company_Name`

Comment: @Jason . . . This may be one of those very, very rare occasions where parentheses are helpful in the `JOIN` clause.  The problem is that you are not aggregating from `item` but from a previous table.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. You're a superstar. Works like a charm and I learned a bunch. Thanks again.